# Shared cache for a shared template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

We use client side template for our web-app.

But we have **tons** of things to generate. Generating template takes like 4 to 5 seconds so we use `- cache(:action_suffix => 'tmpl_timeline') do`in order to cache it.

That results an improvement of response time but only after first visit of project. We want to share the cache of this `tmpl_timeline` to all of our projects.

Each project has a unique url like : `domain.com/[:unique_hash]`

I've seen that we can modify the path for cache on controllers but I don't really know how it can help me.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Is tmpl_timeline a partial that you want shared across various views? Also, does the project endpoint provide different data for the template?

Comment: It looks that rails generate something like `views%2Fdomain.com%2[:unique_hash]%3Faction_suffix%3Dtmpl_timeline` for each project. May be change the path to `domain.com/controller name/action` would do the trick ? Looks risky nope ? For this template there's some internationalisation but nothing to do with data from project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a day of test I've found quite looking good solution.

I made an helper like this

```
    def template_cache
      if !Rails.cache.exist? 'tmpl_timeline_' + I18n.locale.to_s
        Rails.cache.write('tmpl_timeline_' + I18n.locale.to_s, render('shared/templates_timeline') )
      end

      Rails.cache.read( 'tmpl_timeline_' + I18n.locale.to_s ).html_safe
    end
```

Now everytime a deploy I clean rails Cache and this template is cached for every single view that use it